# Dividing by a subquery or finding a proportion of categories in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have a dataset similar to this:

```
Gender Survival
Male      0 
Female     1
Male      0
Male      1
Female     0
```

I need to find a proportion of people survived by gender. Currently I have the following query:
`select gender, count(gender) as 'Survived' from my_table where survival = 1 group by gender;`

Now I need to add a subquery which will divide the count by the total number of people in each gender. So basically I need something like this:

`Male  33%
Female 50%`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `SUM` and `COUNT` to get the average

```
SELECT Gender, ROUND(SUM(Survival = 1) / COUNT(*), 2) * 100
FROM my_table
GROUP BY Gender
```

Here's a [DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/40341/4)

Comment: Well, I wouldn't advocate a keyless table, but each to their own I guess :-(

Answer (score 0):

select gender,(count(survival)/count(*) * 100) as percentage from table_name group by gender,survival;